# Can We encrypt Web services at android app level and decrypt it at server level?

Tags: java, android, web-services, encryption

I'm developing secure android application.I'm using webservices to get data from server. My concern is with the security of the app. If someone decompile my APK(with proguard tool) then webservices are visible to anyone.
 can we encrypt the web services at app level, and while calling it will decrypt at server end? 
 Does this affect the response time of webservice? 
If yes then what is the best solution to encrypt web services in android app?

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "encrypt"? Data encryption? Or do you want to hide the API? Security by obscurity is no security ... Of course any encryption/decryption will affect performance.

Comment: I think you want to encrypt parameters data that you are using in your web services. if yes then you can do this.

Comment: Can we hide the API? Does this affect to performance?